# JavaEE: Question about design

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I have a JSF page that will create a new `Comment`. I have the managed bean of that page to be `RequestScoped` managed bean.

```
@ManagedBean(name="PostComment")
@RequestScoped
public class PostComment { 
    private Comment comment = null;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{A}")
    private A a; //A is a ViewScoped Bean

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{B}")
    private B b; //B is a ViewScoped Bean

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        comment = new Comment();
    }

    // setters and getters for comment and all the managed property variable
    ...

    public void postComment(String location){
        //persist the new comment
        ...
        if(location.equals("A")){
            //update the comment list on page A 
            a.updateListOnA();
        }else if(location.equals("B")){
            //update the comment list on page B
            b.updateListOnB();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code above, 2 ViewScoped bean A and B will both use method `postComment()`. And both will have component bind to attribute `comment`, so both will access getter `getComment()` from bean `PostComment`. The problem I am having right now is that, if I am on A, constructor of A will load, but it will also load constructor of bean B (because of the bean injection using ManagedProperty). This make my page load twice as slow. What would be the best way to solve this problem?

**EDIT**

**One way that I've been thinking is: create two different RequestedScoped bean, `PostAComment`, and `PostBComment`, then `PostAComment` will not need to inject bean `B` anymore, therefore wont load `B` constructor. Will implement this for now, until someone can point me to a better solution**

Answer (score 2):

I think you should remove the `A` and `B` beans and create a service, which will persist the comment depending on the location string. The `PostComment` bean should call this method.

After posting a comment on any page, that page should be refreshed and the comments should be loaded again from the database.

EDIT:

Service is just a buzzword, it can be a session bean or just a simple java class:

```
public class CommentService {

    public void comment(Comment comment, String location) {
        //persist the comment
    }

    //other methods like loading the comments from db
}
```

After refactoring your original bean should look like this:

```
@ManagedBean(name="PostComment")
@RequestScoped
public class PostComment { 
    private Comment comment = null;
    private CommentService commentService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        comment = new Comment();
        commentSetvice = new CommentService();
    }

    // setters and getters for comment
    ...

    public void postComment(String location){
        commentService.comment(comment, location);
    }
}
```

I don't know what A and B contains but this code is enough for adding a comment. To display comments you should create other beans, which load the comments from the database.

Comment: I am not too familiar with service. You think you can put some sample code to lead me a bit? Plus if I change to service, can I still keep those logics that I have in bean A and B? There are quite a few methods inside those two beans